# How to allow an EC2 instance access to its own tags from the OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need to create an IAM managed policy that allows a given EC2 instance to see its own tags from the OS (Linux). I've been able to do this by setting the policy as:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1473154086000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeTags"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The above lets me run ec2-describe-tags from the instance just fine but sees all tags from all resources. I want to restrict it to only seeing its own tags. I've tried to use the EC2 instance ARN as the resource but that did not work. I've also tried using a condition of the IP of the instance; no luck. I'd really like to lock this down if possible; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action ec2:DescribeTags is not a "resource-level", so, you cannot limit at specific resource. 
See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions

Comment: That'd explain why my attempts failed and all examples I found on the internet were open. Good to know, thanks so much for the answer and link!